# setting of intel EPT Accessed and dirty FLags for guest page tables

Tags: intel, virtualization, kvm

I am reading Intel virtualization manual where manual says that if bit 6 of EPTP(a VM execution control field) is set, the processor will set the Accessed and dirty bits in relevant EPT entries according to some rules.

I am trying to understand that if processor sets A/D bits in EPT on access and modification of relevant pages how guest Operating will get benefit from this setting as guest Os has no access to EPT. In my understanding A/D bits are used by memory manager of the OS for optimization and swapping algorithms and there is no role of these bits in page walker.

I(being programmer of VMM) have to add code in VMM to search the relevant entry in GPA space and mark the bits accordingly? 
If this is the case then how can we say that these bits are set with out the knowledge of VMM?
kvm way of dealing this issue will be a good answer also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the guest OS would not benefit from the access and dirty bits in the EPT from being set.  As you stated the guest does not typically have access to the EPT.  This is purely for the hypervisor/VMM.  It is analogous to the dirty and access bit in a process page table, the process does not use it, only the OS.

With regard to your second question, it is a bit unclear so I'm not sure what you are asking.  However, the hardware will mark the access and dirty bits assuming it has been set up correctly, you do not have to do it manually.

Comment: it means my understanding that "guest os also needs A/D bits to ...... so Intel introduces EPT A/D bits" is totally wrong. Plz clear me  how guest OS performs swapping and other memory optimizations with out A/D bits.

Comment: @shami The guest OS still has its own page table (guest physical to guest virtual) with its own A/D bits so it can perform swapping of a *process* within the guest.  Swapping of one or more guests would be performed by the hypervisor.

Comment: who will set the A/D bits in guest and a swap occur in guest will move down to physical pages?

Comment: The A/D bits are set in the guest via the MMU, just as they would be without virtualization.  And yes everything eventually goes down to a physical frame, but the guest OS does not need to know what the host physical address is to perform a swap of its own guest physical memory, it will just use the guest physical address and write that page to the (emulated) guest hard drive.

Comment: with out virtualization A/D bits are used for memory related optimization solutions such as efficient swapping, paging, replacement algos. In virtualization, guest OS has no access to physical RAM, what it will do with its own tables will have no effect on RAM. secondly these bits are set by processor not OS in native system. then in case of VM, who will set these bits. your patience is appreciated plz bear my lack of knowledge

Comment: Yes in virtualization the guest has no access to physical RAM but it has access to guest physical memory which for most intents and purposes it can treat as physical memory, that is the point of virtualization.  All the optimizations you just mentioned will be done in **guest** physical memory, it makes no sense for the guest OS to try to do them in host physical memory.  As I said the MMU is still being used to do **guest** physical to guest virtual address translation and will set the appropriate dirty/access bits in the **guest** page table data structures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87380/discussion-between-missimer-and-shami).

Comment: the optimization performed by guest will effect the host optimization or these optimizations are just illusion for guest with out benefiting the host (real benefit). In simplistic way if guest swap or page out page, the underlying backing physical frame will be released on not?